# react-hook-form failed validating with the required value in bulmaCalendar

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, bulma

I have this part in my form

```
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(getData)} className="box">
                <div className="controls">
                    <input id="createstarttime" type="date" className="input" value={createStartTime} onChange={(e) => setCreateStartTime(e.target.value)} {...register('createstarttime', { required: "Please select a date" })}/>
                    {errors.createstarttime && <p className="help is-danger">{errors.createstarttime.message}</p>}
                </div>
        </form>
```

When I pressed submit even if I had by the value selected it was still validated as failing the "required" requirement as if I didn't input anything.

[image]

This is the only field with the validation; when I set the "required" to false, the confirmation will pass.

Edit1: Ok so I have tried you.com and it gave me a sample code but it also doesn't work https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-fog-lzqgdt

Does these 2 library actually use togather?